# How do i run a ordinal regression using stats model?

Tags: python, statsmodels, ordinal

I would like to run an ordinal regression model in stats model and someone posted this (from statsmodels.miscmodels.ordinal_model import OrderedModel) however it doesnt seem to work.
I also checked on stats models website and ordered models dont appear on there.

Has anyone done an oridinal logistic regression in Python?

Comment: OrderedModel is currently only in the repository and has not been included in a release yet.

Comment: Are there other packages I could use for an ordered model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[statsmodel now has an ordinal regression with OrderedModel](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/ordinal_regression.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can import the `OrderedModel` function from `statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model` like `from statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model import OrderedModel`

Answer (score 0):

Due to the ease of analyzing model results (more R like) I would like to use statsmodels to run an ordinal logistic regression as well, but in Python, unless you use rpy2, the only other option I know of is using mord.

from mord import LogisticAT